# Using special character ? in sed

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I am trying to replace phone numbers of the following format using sed:

+1(123)456-7890

Where `+` and the following `1` are optional. Other digits are arbitrary, but the format has to be the same (i.e. +1(123)456-7890, 1(321)456-0987, (222)555-9900 should match)

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348166/using-with-sed/4348661#4348661) question that I either need to use extended regular expressions option or escape all occurrences of `{` `}` and `?` if I want to use them as special characters. Since `--regexp-extended` is not available in my version of sed, I chose to escape special characters.

This is what I tried so far:

`sed 's/+\?1\?([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/test/g'`

Doesn't match the numbers of the format that I specified.

The closest I could get is this:

`sed 's/([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/test/g'`

This matches (222)555-9900 and like, but obviously doesn't match numbers with `+1` or `+` or `1` in the beginning.

I am a little lost, since I've tried lots of different ways to match 0 or 1 of previous expression and none of them worked.

Just in case it might be helpful: I am using sed that was pre-installed on my Macbook.

Comment: I think your sed supports extended regex with `-r` or `-E` switch . From terminal run `man sed` to verify correct option. Also you can substitute special chars easilly with their ascii hex code. For example use `sed 's/\x31/replace/g'` to match and replace number1. See `man ascii` for the whole list

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou It worked with `-E`; didn't notice that option since I was looking for `-r`. Only had to escape round brackets in this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `*` or `\?` to group. For example: `\(abc\)\?` mean "text 'abc' can be present or not".

For your case, solution is:

```
sed 's/\(+\?1\)\?([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/test/'
```

or

```
sed -E 's/(\+?1)?\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/test/'
```

BTW, in Macbook you have BSD sed. In linux usually used GNU sed (which also support '-E' flags as alias to '-r'). So better always to use '-E' for portability.

Comment: Although I figured out how to do it using extended expressions, as the comment suggested, I am still curious how to match the phone numbers of this format without extended expressions. The first solution that you provided doesn't work for me.

Comment: strange. try `sed 's/\(+\{,1\}1\)\{,1\}([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/test/'`. There `\{,1\}` (or `\{0,1\}` is same as `\?`

Comment: `sed 's/\(+\{,1\}1\)\{,1\}([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/test/‌​'` results in the following error: `sed: 1: "s/\+\{,1\}1\{,1\}([0-9] ...": RE error: invalid repetition count(s)`. If `\{,1\}` is replaced with `\{0,1\}`, I get this error `sed: 1: "s/\+\{0,1\}1\{0,1\}([0- ...": bad flag in substitute command: '�'`.

Comment: Just try in on FreeBSD (as I know sed ported to MacOS from FreeBSD). First variant of regexp I get same error as you, but this one works fine `printf "+1(123)456-7890\n1(321)456-0987\n(222)555-9900\n" | sed 's/\(+\{0,1\}1\)\{0,1\}([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}/test/'`

Comment: It works now. I think I missed something when replacing `\{,1\}` with `\{0,1\}`. Thank you!